# Using Select INTO Statement in Mysql Trigger based on If Condition

Tags: mysql, triggers, conditional-statements

I want to write a trigger. 
The trigger works in the following manner :

When table R_published gets a new entry, based on a column value in the entry(R_published.whichPublishable) it needs to copy a row from either the project_task_goodread_master table or the  project_document_master table into the R_publishedGoodReads OR  R_publishedDocuments tables respectively.

I have written the following trigger and I'm getting the  error : "#1327 - Undeclared variable: R_publishedGoodReads"

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_after_published

    AFTER INSERT ON R_published

    FOR EACH ROW

    BEGIN

    IF (NEW.whichPublishable=1) THEN

        SELECT *  INTO R_publishedGoodReads FROM project_task_goodread_master 
WHERE

 goodReadID= new.publishedItemId;

    ELSEIF (NEW.whichPublishable=2) THEN 

      SELECT * INTO R_publishedDocuments FROM project_document_master where 

 documentID=new.publishedItemId;

      END IF 

END
```

Is there anything wrong with the syntax ? Do I need to declare the table name that I am using for insert ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL doesn't support SELECT...INTO TABLE. See [MySQL Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/ansi-diff-select-into-table.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try instead:

```
IF (NEW.whichPublishable=1) THEN
    INSERT INTO R_publishedGoodReads (col1, col2...)
    SELECT col1, col2... FROM project_task_goodread_master 
    WHERE goodReadID= new.publishedItemId;
```

Comment: CREATE TRIGGER trigger_after_published

    AFTER INSERT ON R_published

    FOR EACH ROW

    BEGIN

    IF (NEW.whichPublishable=1) THEN

        INSERT INTO R_publishedGoodReads SELECT  *  FROM project_task_goodread_master WHERE goodReadID= new.publishedItemId;

    ELSEIF (NEW.whichPublishable=2) THEN 

     INSERT INTO R_publishedDocuments
     SELECT * FROM project_document_master 
where 

 documentID=new.publishedItemId;

      END IF 

END;

Comment: It still gives me the folliwing error : #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 11

Comment: Not sure what line 11 is exactly, but try explicitly listing the column names you are inserting.  `INSERT INTO R_publishedGoodReads (col1, col2) SELECT col1, col2` rather than `INSERT INTO R_publishedGoodReads SELECT *`

Comment: delimiter #

CREATE TRIGGER trigger_after_published 
AFTER INSERT ON R_published 
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN 
CASE WHEN (NEW.whichPublishable=1) 
THEN 
INSERT INTO R_publishedGoodReads 
SELECT * FROM project_task_goodread_master WHERE goodReadID= new.publishedItemId; 
WHEN (NEW.whichPublishable=2) 
THEN
 INSERT INTO R_publishedDocuments 
SELECT * FROM project_document_master where documentID=new.publishedItemId; 

 END#
delimiter ; This worked ! But somehow it doesn't list my trigger in 'show trigger' query results, neither does it act right when I add a row to the R_published.